# Delphi 2006 possibility to display warnings for unused constants

Tags: delphi, constants

Is there a possibility to make Delphi compiler display a warning for each constant that is defined but not used?

I am currently using Delphi 2006 and have several units full of resourcestrings, which are used throughout the project, and since the project is quite old, most of them aren't used anymore, although they remain in the units.

Alternatively I'm looking for a way to indicate such constants.

Comment: What about all of the constants defined in the VCL? I think you would get swamped with warnings if such a warning existed.

Comment: IF such a warning existed, a way to identify constants in VCL might also exist, also i use prefixes in constant names, so even if i would get swamped it wouldn't be that hard to identify constants i would need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi has no features in the program that warn or indicate constants that are not used. It can do unused local variables or unused private fields, but not unused constants.

You need to look at one of the 3rd party static code analysis tools, e.g. [Peganza Pascal Analyzer](http://peganza.com/#PAL). However, I would not be surprised if there were no tools that reported what you want.

Comment: Any suggestions for such tools would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, There's Peganza, link added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way might be to comment out the resource strings, and then uncomment just those that are needed to make the code compile.

Comment: This works, yes, but when there's thousands of them it gets complicated.

Comment: @ertx: Not really. Comment out blocks of them at once, and compile. The compiler will tell you which ones you need to un-comment because they're used. Once you've checked all the blocks, delete lines that are still commented out.  Repeat this for each file of constant definitions.